# How to build Principal Component Analysis (PCA) correlation circle from PCA object made with the package recipes?

Tags: r, pca, r-recipes, factominer

**Context:** Tidymodels framework make use of a common grammar to build model. However, the `FactoMineR` and `factoextra` packages are not part of it. Instead, the package `recipes` is used.

**Problem:** in order to standardize my data analysis workflow, I try to use `recipes` and the tidymodels grammar to make an PCA. However, I cannot figure out how to get comparable outputs from the `FactoMineR` and the `recipes` approaches.

**Question:** How to build the correlation circle and other graphical representations, similar to `FactoMineR::PCA()` from an object made with `recipes::step_pca()`?

**What I tried so far:** I compared the PCA output form packages `recipes`, `FactoMineR` and `stats`, trying to identify "equivalent" information. However I do not understand how to make graphical representations equivalent to those made with `FactoMineR`, but using `recipes` + `ggplot`.

**Here is some code to work with:**

**Using recipes:**

```r
# Using recipes ----
library(recipes)
rec_iris <- recipe(~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_pca(all_predictors())
prep_rec <- prep(rec_iris)
bake(prep_rec, new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 150 × 4
#>      PC1     PC2     PC3      PC4
#>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 -2.26 -0.478   0.127   0.0241 
#>  2 -2.07  0.672   0.234   0.103  
#>  3 -2.36  0.341  -0.0441  0.0283 
#>  4 -2.29  0.595  -0.0910 -0.0657 
#>  5 -2.38 -0.645  -0.0157 -0.0358 
#>  6 -2.07 -1.48   -0.0269  0.00659
#>  7 -2.44 -0.0475 -0.334  -0.0367 
#>  8 -2.23 -0.222   0.0884 -0.0245 
#>  9 -2.33  1.11   -0.145  -0.0268 
#> 10 -2.18  0.467   0.253  -0.0398 
#> # ℹ 140 more rows
# I can get useful information using:
prep_rec %>% tidy(2, type = "variance")
#> # A tibble: 16 × 4
#>    terms                          value component id       
#>    <chr>                          <dbl>     <int> <chr>    
#>  1 variance                      2.92           1 pca_OMBbk
#>  2 variance                      0.914          2 pca_OMBbk
#>  3 variance                      0.147          3 pca_OMBbk
#>  4 variance                      0.0207         4 pca_OMBbk
#>  5 cumulative variance           2.92           1 pca_OMBbk
#>  6 cumulative variance           3.83           2 pca_OMBbk
#>  7 cumulative variance           3.98           3 pca_OMBbk
#>  8 cumulative variance           4              4 pca_OMBbk
#>  9 percent variance             73.0            1 pca_OMBbk
#> 10 percent variance             22.9            2 pca_OMBbk
#> 11 percent variance              3.67           3 pca_OMBbk
#> 12 percent variance              0.518          4 pca_OMBbk
#> 13 cumulative percent variance  73.0            1 pca_OMBbk
#> 14 cumulative percent variance  95.8            2 pca_OMBbk
#> 15 cumulative percent variance  99.5            3 pca_OMBbk
#> 16 cumulative percent variance 100              4 pca_OMBbk
prep_rec %>% tidy(2, type = "coef")
#> # A tibble: 16 × 4
#>    terms          value component id       
#>    <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
#>  1 Sepal.Length  0.521  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  2 Sepal.Width  -0.269  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  3 Petal.Length  0.580  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  4 Petal.Width   0.565  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  5 Sepal.Length -0.377  PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  6 Sepal.Width  -0.923  PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  7 Petal.Length -0.0245 PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  8 Petal.Width  -0.0669 PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  9 Sepal.Length  0.720  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 10 Sepal.Width  -0.244  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 11 Petal.Length -0.142  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 12 Petal.Width  -0.634  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 13 Sepal.Length  0.261  PC4       pca_OMBbk
#> 14 Sepal.Width  -0.124  PC4       pca_OMBbk
#> 15 Petal.Length -0.801  PC4       pca_OMBbk
#> 16 Petal.Width   0.524  PC4       pca_OMBbk
```

**Using FactoMineR:**

```r
# Using FactoMineR ----
library(FactoMineR)
pca_facto <- FactoMineR::PCA(iris[, 1:4])
```

[image][image]

**Using stats**

```r
# Using stats ----
pca_stats <- stats::prcomp(~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE)
```

Now lets try to compare the content of the objects we just made:

```r
# Equivalent objects:
prep_rec %>% tidy(2, type = "variance"); pca_facto$eig; summary(pca_stats)
#> # A tibble: 16 × 4
#>    terms                          value component id       
#>    <chr>                          <dbl>     <int> <chr>    
#>  1 variance                      2.92           1 pca_OMBbk
#>  2 variance                      0.914          2 pca_OMBbk
#>  3 variance                      0.147          3 pca_OMBbk
#>  4 variance                      0.0207         4 pca_OMBbk
#>  5 cumulative variance           2.92           1 pca_OMBbk
#>  6 cumulative variance           3.83           2 pca_OMBbk
#>  7 cumulative variance           3.98           3 pca_OMBbk
#>  8 cumulative variance           4              4 pca_OMBbk
#>  9 percent variance             73.0            1 pca_OMBbk
#> 10 percent variance             22.9            2 pca_OMBbk
#> 11 percent variance              3.67           3 pca_OMBbk
#> 12 percent variance              0.518          4 pca_OMBbk
#> 13 cumulative percent variance  73.0            1 pca_OMBbk
#> 14 cumulative percent variance  95.8            2 pca_OMBbk
#> 15 cumulative percent variance  99.5            3 pca_OMBbk
#> 16 cumulative percent variance 100              4 pca_OMBbk
#>        eigenvalue percentage of variance cumulative percentage of variance
#> comp 1 2.91849782             72.9624454                          72.96245
#> comp 2 0.91403047             22.8507618                          95.81321
#> comp 3 0.14675688              3.6689219                          99.48213
#> comp 4 0.02071484              0.5178709                         100.00000
#> Importance of components:
#>                           PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4
#> Standard deviation     1.7084 0.9560 0.38309 0.14393
#> Proportion of Variance 0.7296 0.2285 0.03669 0.00518
#> Cumulative Proportion  0.7296 0.9581 0.99482 1.00000
```

Now, why are these different?

```r
# Why are these different?
prep_rec %>% tidy(2, type = "coef"); pca_stats$rotation # --> different form $var from an abject made with FactoMineR::PCA()
#> # A tibble: 16 × 4
#>    terms          value component id       
#>    <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
#>  1 Sepal.Length  0.521  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  2 Sepal.Width  -0.269  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  3 Petal.Length  0.580  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  4 Petal.Width   0.565  PC1       pca_OMBbk
#>  5 Sepal.Length -0.377  PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  6 Sepal.Width  -0.923  PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  7 Petal.Length -0.0245 PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  8 Petal.Width  -0.0669 PC2       pca_OMBbk
#>  9 Sepal.Length  0.720  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 10 Sepal.Width  -0.244  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 11 Petal.Length -0.142  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 12 Petal.Width  -0.634  PC3       pca_OMBbk
#> 13 Sepal.Length  0.261  PC4       pca_OMBbk
#> 14 Sepal.Width  -0.124  PC4       pca_OMBbk
#> 15 Petal.Length -0.801  PC4       pca_OMBbk
#> 16 Petal.Width   0.524  PC4       pca_OMBbk
#>                     PC1         PC2        PC3        PC4
#> Sepal.Length  0.5210659 -0.37741762  0.7195664  0.2612863
#> Sepal.Width  -0.2693474 -0.92329566 -0.2443818 -0.1235096
#> Petal.Length  0.5804131 -0.02449161 -0.1421264 -0.8014492
#> Petal.Width   0.5648565 -0.06694199 -0.6342727  0.5235971
pca_facto$var
#> $coord
#>                   Dim.1      Dim.2       Dim.3       Dim.4
#> Sepal.Length  0.8901688 0.36082989 -0.27565767 -0.03760602
#> Sepal.Width  -0.4601427 0.88271627  0.09361987  0.01777631
#> Petal.Length  0.9915552 0.02341519  0.05444699  0.11534978
#> Petal.Width   0.9649790 0.06399985  0.24298265 -0.07535950
#> 
#> $cor
#>                   Dim.1      Dim.2       Dim.3       Dim.4
#> Sepal.Length  0.8901688 0.36082989 -0.27565767 -0.03760602
#> Sepal.Width  -0.4601427 0.88271627  0.09361987  0.01777631
#> Petal.Length  0.9915552 0.02341519  0.05444699  0.11534978
#> Petal.Width   0.9649790 0.06399985  0.24298265 -0.07535950
#> 
#> $cos2
#>                  Dim.1       Dim.2       Dim.3        Dim.4
#> Sepal.Length 0.7924004 0.130198208 0.075987149 0.0014142127
#> Sepal.Width  0.2117313 0.779188012 0.008764681 0.0003159971
#> Petal.Length 0.9831817 0.000548271 0.002964475 0.0133055723
#> Petal.Width  0.9311844 0.004095980 0.059040571 0.0056790544
#> 
#> $contrib
#>                  Dim.1       Dim.2     Dim.3     Dim.4
#> Sepal.Length 27.150969 14.24440565 51.777574  6.827052
#> Sepal.Width   7.254804 85.24748749  5.972245  1.525463
#> Petal.Length 33.687936  0.05998389  2.019990 64.232089
#> Petal.Width  31.906291  0.44812296 40.230191 27.415396
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first plot can be made by mapping the first two principal components to the X and Y axes respectively. To match the example you shared I label the points using `ggrepel`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(recipes)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggforce)

iris_pca <- recipe(~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_pca(all_predictors(), res = TRUE) %>%
  prep() 
  
iris_pca %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(PC1, PC2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = id)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, lty = 2) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Getting the values for the circle plot requires getting the loadings from the prepped object. This is what `matrix = 'v'` is doing in the following.

```r
tidy(iris_pca, 2, matrix = 'v') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = component, values_from = value) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = terms)) +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 1)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Can you please visit [Customized plotting of PCA results in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517593/customized-plotting-of-pca-results-in-r)?

Comment: @Seth, many thanks, I did not know about the `matrix = 'v'` argument!

Comment: @Seth, could you tell us where you find documentation about this `matrix` argument?

Comment: Hi @Paul. `step_pca` is using `prcomp`, so you can reference the [documentation for the tidy.prcomp method](https://broom.tidymodels.org/reference/tidy.prcomp.html).